# mod_rewrite with WordPress

Tags: wordpress, mod-rewrite

I'm finding it very hard to understand why the following does not work

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteRule ^category/.+$ category_display.php [L]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]  

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

if I comment out the second rule (WordPress) it will work. I was on the understanding that `[L]` terminates if a match is found...

Can anyone shine a light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just done some research and found the answer. As a test i was just making up a file name expecting it to throw an error saying the file does not exist. But after reading I found that !-f and !-d check to see if the file exists and thats why it was throwing the custom wordpress 404.